# Flutter Dio post request progress tracking for list of flies goes 0 to 100 immediately

Tags: flutter, dio

I have this api function which sends some data as `formData` including a field which contains a list of `MultiPartFile`.

```
static Future<Response> registerVariation(VariationRegistrationForm variationRegistrationForm, int productId) async {
    // Code

    List<File?> nonNullImageFiles = variationRegistrationForm.variationImages!.where((image) => image != null).toList();
    List<Future<MultipartFile>> variationImagesFutures = nonNullImageFiles
        .map(
          (File? image) => MultipartFile.fromFile(image!.path, filename: image.path.split('/').last),
        )
        .toList();
    List<MultipartFile> variationImages = await Future.wait(variationImagesFutures);
    
    // Code

    final Map<String, dynamic> form = {
      'price': variationRegistrationForm.price,
      'quantity': variationRegistrationForm.quantity,
      'is_default': variationRegistrationForm.isPrimary,
      'product_id': productId,
      'varient_images': variationImages,
      'property_values_id': properties
    };

    final FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(form);

    loadingProvider.setLoading(true);

    final Response response = await dio.post(
      '$endPoint/$target',
      options: Options(
        headers: headers,
      ),
      data: formData,
      onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
        loadingProvider.setProgress(((sent / total) * 100).toInt()); // Goes 0 to 100 very fast
      },
    );

    loadingProvider.setLoading(false);

    return response;
  }
```

I don't know how to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70048579/14185442) as it only sends the file as the entire body, any ideas on how I could do it for a list of files in formData?

Comment: What exactly do you want to solve?

Comment: `onSendProgress` isn't sending the actual progress of the uploading process, it is going from 0 to 100 immediately at the start of the request

Answer (score 0):

I found this explanation in [Dio's](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) own document
And I guess the answer to your question is this

Sending a FormData:

```
final formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'dio',
  'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
});
final response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

Uploading multiple files to server by FormData:

```
final formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'dio',
  'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
  'files': [
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text1.txt', filename: 'text1.txt'),
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text2.txt', filename: 'text2.txt'),
  ]
});
final response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

Listening the uploading progress:

```
final response = await dio.post(
  'https://www.dtworkroom.com/doris/1/2.0.0/test',
  data: {'aa': 'bb' * 22},
  onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
    print('$sent $total');
  },
);
```

Comment: This is exactly what im already doing