# Flutter http streamedResponse.stream and streamedResponse.sink

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-http

I'm learning the third example of Flutter http package, this is the base of the code: https://pub.dev/packages/http

> When the request is sent via BaseClient.send, only the headers and whatever data has already been written to **StreamedRequest.stream** will be sent immediately. More data will be sent as soon as it's written to **StreamedRequest.sink**, and when the sink is closed the request will end.

https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedRequest-class.html

1. From the docs, I don't understand how we should write to `StreamedRequest.stream`? (To send data immediately)
2. Isn't StreamedResponse.sink basically where we add our HTTP POST's Request Body: Why does it only accept a `List<int>`? Shouldn't it be a `Map<String, String>`? If it's not then where should we add the request body? `NEW:` Even when I encode it with ut8.encode, it still doesn't show up on Fiddler's WebForms when I'm debugging, how do I send a x-www-form-urlencoded properly?:

Code:

```
userAgentClient = UserAgentClient(userAgent, client);
streamedRequest = http.StreamedRequest('POST', Uri(scheme: 'http', path: '/posts/', host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'));
streamedRequest.sink.add([123, 456]); // It has to be a List<int>

//NEW:
streamedRequest.sink.add(utf8.encode('username=123&password=456'));
streamedRequest.sink.add(utf8.encode('{"username":"123","password":"456"}'));
```

3. Why do I have to close the sink to be able to access StreamedResponse's properties?

`streamedRequest.sink.close();`

**Update:**

```
class UserAgentClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final String userAgent;
  final http.Client client;
  UserAgentClient(this.userAgent, this.client);
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request){
    request.headers['user-agent'] = userAgent;
    return client.send(request);
  }
}

dynamic _status = '';
dynamic _body = '';
dynamic _headers = '';
String _reason = '';
http.Client client = http.Client();
String userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36';
UserAgentClient userAgentClient;
http.StreamedRequest streamedRequest;

void _httpStreamed(){
  userAgentClient = UserAgentClient(userAgent, client);
  streamedRequest = http.StreamedRequest('POST', Uri(scheme: 'http', path: '/posts/', host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'));
  streamedRequest.sink.add(utf8.encode('{"username":"123","password":"456"}'));
  setState(() {
    _status = streamedRequest.url;
    _body = '';
    _headers = '';
    _reason = '';
  });
}

void _httpSend() async{
    http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse;
    streamedResponse = await userAgentClient.send(streamedRequest);
    streamedResponse.stream.listen(
      (value) async{
          _body = http.ByteStream.fromBytes(value);
          _body = await _body.bytesToString();
      },
      onError: (e, sT) {
        SnackBar sBar = SnackBar(content: Text('$e\n$sT',));
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(sBar);
      },
      onDone: () {
        SnackBar sBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Done lol'),);
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(sBar);
      },
    );
    setState(() {
      _body;
      _status = streamedResponse.statusCode;
      _headers = streamedResponse.headers;
      _reason = streamedResponse.reasonPhrase;
    });
  }
}

void _httpClose(){
  if (streamedRequest != null){
    streamedRequest.sink.close();
  }
}
```

So I run the first 2 functions but the `_body` variable doesn't show up on my screen until I run the `_httpClose()` function.

Comment: this updated code that you have made is the fully working version?

Comment: @CassioSeffrin I'm a Flutter learner and I was trying to fully learn the http Flutter package, so I made an application to test everything it has. Since you're interested, I uploaded the fully working version here for you: https://github.com/Saya47/Flutter-http-learning All the code is in one dart file, copy paste it in your flutter test project, and build the app and test everything!

Comment: Thks @Shayan. For now I only need check if these streamed request have worked. I have done it in a different way:

  final request = Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  final StreamedResponse response = await Client().send(request);

Additionally I need configure a timeout, but Client().send haven't the arguments needed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes
2. `Map<String,String>` can not be streamed.
   Streamed means the data is sent in chunks every time a chunk of data is emitted by the stream and the server (or the browsers send buffer) is ready to receive more data.
   `List<int>` can be chunked because it doesn't matter how many bytes are sent at once.
   If you have all data readily available, you probably do not want to use a StreamedRequest, expecially if it is not a blob of data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

`utf8.encode` can be used to encode chunks emitted by a stream, but it doesn't provide a stream by itself, so you can't add the result of `utf8.encode` to a sink.

3. I do not understand that question. What properties doe you want to access and what problems do you run into when you try?

To me it doesn't look like you don't need to use StreamedRequest for your use case.

Comment: Thanks very much, it all makes sense now, for 3, basically when I want to check the response of the server, like the body, it doesn't show up until I close the sink, I'll update my code in a minute.

Comment: Ok, it can't because the request can't be completed before the stream is closed (signalled there won't be any more data) and you can't access the response before the request obviously ;-)