# How to show progress when upload file using http request

Tags: flutter, http

```
Future<void> updateImage(http.MultipartRequest request) async {
    var streamedResponse, response;
    bool Error = false;
    try {
      streamedResponse = await request.send();
      response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    } catch (err) {
      Error = true;
      continuosly = false;
      ErrorMessageDialog(context, err.toString(), () {});
    }
    if (!Error) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        WebAPIResponse Status =
            WebAPIResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        if (Status.Status == '0') {
          continuosly = true;
        } else {
          continuosly = false;
          ErrorMessageDialog(context, Status.ErrorMsg, () {});
        }
      } else {
        continuosly = false;
        ErrorMessageDialog(context, "Lỗi kết nối!", () {});
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> selectImageFromDevice() async {
    final List<XFile> listImageSelected =
        await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage(imageQuality: 40);
    if (listImageSelected.isEmpty) {
      return;
    } else {
      var postUri = Uri.parse(
          "https://myserver");
      var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
      Map<String, String> header = {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      };

      request.fields['ID'] = widget.ct.ID;
      for (var i in listImageSelected) {
        originalImage = File(i.path);
        //nén ảnh
        Uint8List? compressedImage =
            await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(originalImage!.path,
                quality: 40);
        String fileName = i.name;

        request.fields['FileName'] = fileName;
        request.files.add(
          http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('FileContent', compressedImage!,
              filename: fileName),
        );
      }
      request.headers.addAll(header);
      updateImage(request);
    }
  }
```

I am using http package.
Here is the code. I want to show the progress in the real time while data is being send to server.
Also search for same question but nothing work for me ?
The old post is about 2 or 3 year ago and somthing like using stream. Then I still dont know how to take the byte data that sended.
Example that I would like to show: Uploaded 1/5 image or percent: ../100%

Comment: Can you provide the link of the post where the solution does not work for you?

Comment: i try 2 of this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63419646/20004279
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53838367/20004279

Comment: Btw it's better to declare these two variables separately: `http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse; http.Response response;` so you get strong typing

Comment: So do you have any idea to solve this ?