# How to show the current progress on a post request in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, post

i wan't to see the current upload progress on a post request. Is this somehow possible in Flutter/Dart with the http package for example?

I couldn't find any example projects or code snippets to solve this problem.

Maybe there is a callback, but i couldnt find any.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727911/how-to-get-progress-event-while-uploading-file-on-http-multipartrequest-request might help you.

Comment: Hey, they all use a multipart request. But i dont send a file in my body, i have just a big json. But i dont know how to do the same with a json