# Downloading progress in dart:http

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I'm trying to make a progress bar indicator for a downloading file, but if I add a listener to the `StreamedResponse`, the piping works, but does to not finish its future.

```
final client = new http.Client();
http.StreamedResponse response = await client.send(http.Request("GET", Uri.parse('someurl')));

var received = 0;
var length = response.contentLength;

//if I remove this listener, the await below gets completed
var listen = response.stream.listen((List<int> bytes) {
  received += bytes.length;
  print("${(received / length) * 100} %");
});

var sink = downloadFile.openWrite();
await response.stream.pipe(sink);
listen.cancel();
sink.close();
```

On [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/211) they already advised someone that it was supposed to work, but on [StreamedResponse docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedResponse-class.html) stays that `This should always be a single-subscription stream.`. So, adding a listener to calculate the percentage seems to bugs `StreamedResponse` pipe in someway. Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: How to get upload / download progress for http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455131/flutter-how-to-get-upload-download-progress-for-http-requests)

Comment: use `response.stream,map` for example and update your `received` counter there

Comment: Sorry, the day has just started here. I was able to make it work yesterday by watching the length of the file that was being written, that worked, but @pskink solution with map is easier and will work even if you are not writing into a file, I'll these solutions as answers.
Thank you guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@pskink comment let me to this solution that works for every type of `sink` you are using.

```
  var length = response.contentLength;
  var received = 0;
  var sink = downloadFile.openWrite();

  await response.stream.map((s) {
    received += s.length;
    print("${(received / length) * 100} %");
    return s;
  }).pipe(sink);
```

another way to accomplish this, if you are writing into a file, is to watch file length

```
  var length = response.contentLength;
  var sink = downloadFile.openWrite();

  Future.doWhile(() async {
    var received = await downloadFile.length();

    print("${(received / length) * 100} %");
    return received != length;
  });

  await response.stream.pipe(sink);
```

Comment: Can you give a full example?