# Flutter - Determinate Loading in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a case where I am using `FutureBuilder` and while loading I am showing my `CircularProgressIndicator`. Now I want to set a value to the loader but I don't have one and I don't really have any way of knowing how much time will it take to complete the future. My current code is something like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getSoilData(context),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return makeBody();
    }
    
    return LoadingBar();
  },
),
```

So how do I set the value to my progress bar so that the user gets an idea of how much more time the loader is going to take.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible with ```FutureBuilder```

Comment: @EhsanAskari Is there any other way it's possible ??

Comment: Check if this answers your question [How to get upload / download progress for http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455131/flutter-how-to-get-upload-download-progress-for-http-requests)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionState have  wainting

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return makeBody();
    }
else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return LoadingBar();
  },
```

or you can just put an else

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return makeBody();
    }
else {
    return LoadingBar();
  },
```

Comment: That's what I am currently doing right now. I want to add the value to the loading bar so that the user gets an idea of how much more time is it gonna take.